# is stm32f103 programmable via micro usb?

Tags: arm, stm32

I would like to buy following thing to start. I've got tired of arduino and after some research I came across this.

[STM32f103](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ARM-Cortex-M3-STM32F103C8T6-STM32-Minimum-System-Development-Board-/381374722304?hash=item58cbb47100:g:S0cAAOxyni9S~0Fd)

I am wondering what do I need to start programming this board? Is it programmable over micro usb or do I need JTAG cable. Also is there some good starting tutorials for it, cause I haven't found any?

Comment: usually the stm32 chips come with a factory bootloader from which you can use the uart, can you use usb?  not sure. but the datasheet and/or other docs on the st site will tell you.  if you cant find or read those you wont get very far with this part anyway.  Likewise where is the schematic for this board?  How do you know what the usb is hooked up to anyway, or any thing else?  For the money you would need to spend, the $6 for this board plus another $15 for jtag and another $10 for serial, you could have bought two or three neutrinos.

Comment: not all nucleos are created equal.  they all make it easy to just copy the binary over.  but I also prefer ones that the uart just works, some do some dont, and it is sometimes not easy to find in the documentation until you have been burned by it.  I know the f401 and f411 work.  the smaller ones I have a number of those but dont have a list of success vs fail.  you should invest the $10 or $15 in a usb to uart cable or solution anyway (ftdi breakout basically) and that gets around this problem.

Comment: For that board you will need a TTL RS232 converter for the first time or JTAG. Then if you download your own bootloader you can program with USB, also. I have been using STM32duino bootloader and Arduino environment as well, like proposed by user @uint_128t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this document](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00167594.pdf), the STM32F10xxx internal (ROM) bootloader only supports the USART. Therefore, unless the board arrives with an existing USB bootloader, it cannot be initially programmed via the USB port.

However, you can buy an ST-Link or an ST-Link clone to program the board (they are very cheap, as far as programmers go, even the genuine ones). ST-Link programs the board over a [two-wire serial debug connection](http://www.arm.com/products/system-ip/debug-trace/coresight-soc-components/serial-wire-debug.php) (SWDIO and SWCLK). Once you have a programmer, you can use [mbed](https://www.mbed.com/en/) with the STM32F103 Nucleo board as your target, and then download the `.bin` file and flash it to the board with the ST Link command line tools.

However, once you are able to program the board, you can flash a USB bootloader and program it via USB. I have a very similar board (same chip, slightly different board), and I will try flashing a Maple(ish) bootloader and programming it via Arduino or something and report back, give me a few minutes.

**Edit: partial success**

---

I was able to flash [this STM32duino bootloader](https://github.com/rogerclarkmelbourne/STM32duino-bootloader) using my programmer. Plugging the board in on my Mac now enumerates via USB as follows:

```
Maple 003@14100000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000113c5, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (163 ms), retain 14>
```

However, while [this Arduino STM32 library](https://github.com/rogerclarkmelbourne/Arduino_STM32) looks like it should work, I couldn't get it to build. There are a lot of issues with the includes and I'm not going to bother trying to fix up the paths. However, it looks like it ought to work after a bit of fiddling.

---

I also want to point something out. It seems like you are a beginner with respect to ARM development. Because of this, I would highly suggest buying an STM Nucleo board, getting comfortable with it, and then moving to cheaper and less-documented boards like this one. The Nucleo boards are incredibly cheap and considerably better documented than bottom of the barrel boards on eBay.

Comment: Doesn't that microcontroller have a built in bootloader?

Comment: My head is gonna explode from all this information, lol. Thank you anyway, you've helpd me a lot.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Yes, but my understanding is that it doesn't support USB. See [this document](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00167594.pdf), page 21. It looks like the supported peripheral is only the USART. I could be wrong though. I'll edit my answer to clarify the existence of a USART bootloader.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: While its ROM-based built-in bootloader only supports the USART, you can always put your own bootloader into the first part of the flash, and then you may choose which interfaces you want to support.